# I got unserialize error at offset 0 of 115

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5, serialization

I am fetch serialize data from mysql DB and try to unserialize them for further use, however, I got error at offset 0 of 115 bytes

Data I am trying to unserialize :

```
'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:2:"38";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:2;i:1;s:2:"39";}}'
```

And this is my code:

```
  public function retrival(){

$warehouse_data  =DB::table('initial')->select('variable1')
  ->where('option','=',8)
  ->get();


$decode_data=unserialize($warehouse_data);


}
```

Comment: If you `var_dump($warehouse_data)`, what do you get?

Comment: Are the single quotes actually in the data?

Comment: _"error at offset 0 of 115 bytes"_ Your example is only 70 bytes, so I don't think that's the actual data you're trying to unserialize.

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#270 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#267 (1) { ["variable1"]=> string(68) "a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:2:"38";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:2;i:1;s:2:"39";}}" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#266 (1) { ["variable1"]=> string(8) "77865765" } } }

Comment: i got that response

Comment: @Mayur, that just proves that this is not the string that causes the error: "string(68)". See? 68 bytes (Alex counted the quotes too, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a collection representing all the rows of the results, and each row is an object. You need to index it and then access the appropriate column.

```
$warehouse_data  =DB::table('initial')->select('variable1')
  ->where('option','=',8)
  ->first()
  ->variable1;
```

You can also use the `value()` method:

```
$warehouse_data  =DB::table('initial')->select('variable1')
  ->where('option','=',8)
  ->value('variable1');
```

See the Laravel documentation on [Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results)